# List of primitive types for C++

Tags: c++

Is there a function which would return (during compilation of metaprogram) in some form (List) a list of all available primitive types?
Thanks

Comment: Just read the language standard, which prescribes the primitive types which the language must support, or [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_variable_types_and_declarations#Basic_types).

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Note that that's not necessarily an exhaustive list. it's only a minimum, compilers are entirely free to add `__int128`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect question.

What is list of types? `std::list<T>`? or array?

If it is std::list then what is T? T = "std::string"?

List of all types is described in C++ Standard.

```
bool
signed/unsigned char
signed/unsigned short int
signed/unsigned int
signed/unsigned long
size_t
wchar_t
float
double
```

Comment: You're missing `long double` and plain `char`. Furthermore, `size_t` is generally not a distinct type but a typedef.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't - runtime introspection of this kind is not common nor possible nor useful in C++ (what would you do with a **runtime** function that gives you a list of the type names that you actually need to write your code in the first place?).

The primitive types supported by the language are:

```
bool
(unsigned,signed) char
wchar_t
(unsigned) short
(unsigned) int
(unsigned) long
[(unsigned) long long]

float
double
[long double]
```

Individual compilers support more, and many types are commonly available but implemented by means of typedefing the above primitive types (i.e. `uint32_t` etc.).

For a full list, have a look at the language specification.

Comment: `long long` isn't a standard type.

Comment: I never said that this function will be runtime.

Answer (score 4):

The full list of Fundamental types you can find in C++ Standard §3.9.1:

```
char

signed char
short int
int
long int

unsigned char
unsigned short int
unsigned int
unsigned long int

wchar_t

bool

float
double
long double

void
```

Note that plain `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are three distinct types. C++ Standard also defines `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` (they're not fundamental though).

You can expect that every standard conformant compiler will support all these types. Each specific compiler can support more additional types supported as an extension.